# The Standard seems to support (the snippet below compiles) a static data member having the same type as the class itself

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members, language-lawyer

Where specifically is this covered in the Standard? I found §9.2/10: `Non-static (9.4) data members shall not have incomplete types. In particular, a class C shall not contain a non-static member of class C, but it can contain a pointer or reference to an object of class C.`, but this doesn't seem to directly support the issue at hand.

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    int i;
    static A a;
};

A A::a{10};

int main() {
    std::cout << A::a.i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I think that is because when you *declare* `a` it has an incomplete type but since it is a static variable the compiler does not need to know its size until its *definition*, which occurs when the type `A` is well defined and complete.

Comment: I particularly like `struct A { static A a; } A::a;` :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++11 9.4.2/2:

> The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified `void`.

Comment: Could you add a little bit of explanation of exactly what this means? Not sure I understand it entirely.

Comment: @AJMansfield The OP asked where in the standard incomplete types are allowed as `static` data members.  MikeSeymour found the quote that says that `static` data members can have (non-void) incomplete types at declaration.  Is there something else in particular you don't understand?

Comment: He quoted _the_ holy Standard, no explanation necessary.

Comment: @AJMansfield: Presumably, you understand "The declaration of a static data member in its class definition"; that's the `static A a;` declaration in the example. It's just a declaration, not a definition - there needs to be a separate definition outside the class definition (`A A::a{10};` in the example). Being a declaration, the type doesn't have to be complete - it can be a class type that's been declared but not fully defined, as `A` is at that point. (The last bit just says that it can't have type `void` - not relevant here).